# Properties of a a group $G$ of order $2021$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a group of order $2021$. Then which of the following statements are true:
>
> (1) $G$ is a cyclic group.
>
> (2) $G$ is non-abelian.
>
> (3) All subgroups of $G$ are normal.
>
> (4) Number of non-trivial subgroups is 3
>
> (5) $G$ is a simple group.
>
> (6) $G\simeq \mathbb Z_{2021}$
>
> (7) If $a_1+a_2+...+a_{2021}$ is class equation of $G$ then $a_i=a_j\;\forall i,j\in \{1,2,...,2021\}$
>
> (8) If $H\le G$ then $G/H$ is always cyclic.
>
> (9) Non-trivial subgroup of $G$ may not be cyclic.

Assuming $G$ is a cyclic group I got:
(1) True;(2) False;(3) True;

(4) If by trivial subgroup you mean only $\{e_G\}$ then True, but if $\{e_G\}$ and $G$ are both considered as trivial subgroups then False;

(5) False (6) True;(7) True;(8) True;(9) Same argument as question (4), since $G$ is not simple.

But does there exist a non-cyclic group of order $2021$. If yes then which of the statements will be True.

Comment: I don't know how to format questions and \\ is not working for newline. Format it if you wish. And how to use newline ? The FAQ for MathJax have no answer to it.

Answer (score 2):

A group of order $pq$, where $p\lt q$ and $p\not|(q-1)$ is always cyclic. This is well-known.

Thus we have a cyclic group and the answers are all fairly trivial.  The class equation is $\underbrace{1+\dots+1}_{\text{2021-times}}$.  Any quotient or subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

Every group $G$ of order $2021$ is cyclic. To see this, observe that $2021=43\cdot 47$, so any group of order $2021$ has a normal subgroup $H_1$ of order $43$ and another normal subgroup $H_2$ of order $47$. Since $H_1$ acts on $H_2$ by conjugation, there is a homomorphism $H_1\to \text{Aut}(H_2) \cong \mathbb Z/46\mathbb Z$. But $43$ is coprime to $46$, so this homomorphism has trivial image, and we conclude that $H_1$ commutes with $H_2$.

Thus $G$ is a direct product $H_1\times H_2 \cong \mathbb Z/43\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/47\mathbb Z \cong \mathbb Z/2021\mathbb Z$.

This is a special case of the general setup of *semidirect products*.

For your other question, the trivial subgroup is $\{e\}$, and all other subgroups (including $G$ itself) are nontrivial.

Comment: How is it concluded that $H_1$ acts on $H_2$ by conjugation?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel  $H_2$ is normal.  So conjugation by any element of the group defines an automorphism of $H_2$.